# Difference signature / asymmetric encryption (PQC)

Tags: public-key, signature, post-quantum-cryptography

The NIST is currently trying to select new standards for post-quantum cryptography.
The two main categories for the candidates are "Public-key Encryption and Key-establishment Algorithms" and "Digital Signature Algorithms".

The signature algorithms are based on public-key encryption algorithms. Thus, why to separate these two categories ? Is it a matter of implementation, or of performance maybe ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question's statement

> The signature algorithms are based on public-key encryption algorithms

goes straight against accepted wisdom. Which is that signature and public-key encryption are separate beasts, and we know no way to build¹ the former from the later, or vice versa (while keeping the same key generation procedure, or efficiently; see comments).

This explains the two categories “Public-key Encryption and Key-establishment Algorithms” and “Digital Signature Algorithms”.

---

¹ Sure, we can build both kinds from [trapdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function) [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). The standard examples are RSA signature like [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A78%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C314%2Cnull%5D) and RSA encryption like [RSAES-OAEP](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A44%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C640%2Cnull%5D), both built from the textbook RSA trapdoor permutation  of $[0,n)$ per $x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$. But there are many other useful constructions of signature and public-key encryption.

Comment: We *do* know how to generically construct signatures from PKE. Just not particularly efficiently.

Comment: @Maeher : is that with the same public/private key pair, or rebuild from scratch the way we can build hashes, then (kinda) signature ?

Comment: No, not at all. It would be a Rube Goldbergesque construction using the key generation procedure as a OWF and building a signature scheme from that. (Crucially this does involve CRHF which we have basically *no* idea how to construct from general assumptions) This isn't useful, but it's in contrast to the other direction, where not even such a construction is known.

Answer (score 3):

Like fgrieu said, not all public-key algorithms are based on bijective trapdoor permutations.

If the standardization effort looked for a general-purpose bijective permutation, then we may very probably miss some special-purpose constructs that're more efficient when designed specifically for PKE/KEM or DSS.

I mean, designing something that fits the need of both functions may make the result significantly less efficient.